# C# ArgumentOutOfRangeException stream.Read

Tags: c#

как исправить ошибку ArgumentOutOfRangeException в строке

```
while((read = stream.Read(buffer, total, 1000)) != 0)
```

Полный текст метода:

```
private void getFrame()
{
    string sourceURL = "https://geocam.tv/streamer/2222.mjpg";
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1280 * 800];
    int read, total = 0;
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sourceURL);
    WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
    Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
    while((read = stream.Read(buffer, total, 1000)) != 0)
    {
        total += read;
    }
    Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, total));
    pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
}
```

Я хочу транслировать видео из странички https://geocam.tv/streamer/2222.mjpg

Comment: а размера буффера точно достаточно?

Comment: @pavel как определить что достаточно

Comment: ну например использовать динамические массивы ArrayList к примеру и не заботится об этом. И стоит полностью строку сообщения привести, там написано к какому индексу было обращение.

Comment: @NoProgress, можно попробовать [`Length`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.stream.length(v=vs.110).aspx) проверить

Comment: @pavel я не разбераюсь в этой теме покажите пример

Comment: хм, _mjpg_ это же не картинка. Фактически ты пробуешь бесконечно читать

Comment: @Grundy Length чего и куда его поставить

Comment: @NoProgress, лучше добавь в вопрос что именно ты пытаешься сделать

Comment: @Grundy добавил

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51736/discussion-between-grundy-and-noprogress).

Comment: @NoProgress не легче ли воспользоваться `HttpClient`, код будет в разы проще.

Comment: вместо этого лучше юзать `ReadToEnd()`

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, это не тот случай

Answer (score 3):

воспользовался MJPEG Decoder

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    MjpegDecoder _mjpeg;
    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _mjpeg = new MjpegDecoder();
        _mjpeg.FrameReady += mjpeg_FrameReady;

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _mjpeg.ParseStream(new Uri("https://geocam.tv/streamer/2222.mjpg"));
    }

    private void mjpeg_FrameReady(object sender, FrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = e.Bitmap;
    }
```

и все работает